# Three-player tournament with Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Consider the following problem, from Tijms's *Understanding Probability*:

> Three equally matched opponents decide to have a ping-pong
>   tournament. Two people play against each other in each game. Drawing lots, it
>   is determined who are playing the first game. The winner of a game stays on
>   and plays against the person not active in that game. The games continue until
>   somebody has won two games in a row. What is the probability that the person
>   not active in the first game is the ultimate winner?

Let's call the three players A, B, and C.

To solve this problem using a Markov chain, I introduce the following states:

- state 0: there is going to be a match between A and B, and nobody has won the previous match because there have been no previous matches. I will denote this state with the shortcut $(AB, 0)$ (this is the initial state);
- state 1: there is going to be a match between A and B, and A won the previous match. Shortcut: $(AB,A)$;
- state 2: there is going to be a match between A and B, and B won the previous match. Shortcut: $(AB,B)$;
- state 3: there is going to be a match between A and C, and A won the previous match. Shortcut: $(AC,A)$;
- state 4: there is going to be a match between A and C, and C won the previous match. Shortcut: $(AC,C)$;
- state 5: there is going to be a match between B and C, and B won the previous match: $(BC,B)$;
- state 6: there is going to be a match between B and C, and C won the previous match: $(BC,C)$;
- state 7: A has won two matches in a row;
- state 8: B has won two matches in a row;
- state 9: C has won two matches in a row.

The last three states should be absorbing states.

By considering all the possible games, one can easily write down the nonzero entries of the transition probability matrix:
$$
\begin{gathered}
 p_{03} & p_{05} & p_{17} & p_{15} & p_{23} & p_{28} & p_{37} & p_{36}
 & p_{41} & p_{49} & p_{58} & p_{54} & p_{62} & p_{69},
\end{gathered}
$$
which are all equal to $\frac12$.

Already after 20 matrix multiplication, we have the following quite stable probabilities:
$$
p^{(20)}_{07} = p^{(20)}_{08} = 0.3571, \qquad
p^{(20)}_{09} = 0.2857,
$$
so the probability that the person not active in the first game wins is 0.2857.

Does the result seem right? Intuitively, I would expect that the player not involved in the first game has lower probability of winning, because if it loses there won't be any more matches.

I noticed that building the probability transition matrix is quite tedious, is there a more systematic way to doing this?

Answer (score 1):

have you come across hitting probabilities? If not see theorem 1.3.2 in these notes: http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s13.pdf

These let you set up equations relating the hitting probabilities starting from each state, which can be solved. Remember to exploit symmetry to save computation.

Comment: Thanks, I will read the notes and retry the computation with hitting probabilities.